# Own annotation for testng

Tags: java-8, annotations, testng

How can I write my own annotation that will do something before starting the method using the `@Test` annotation?

For example: create test's user

I can't use standard testng annotation such as `@BeforeTest`, because they run for each test. It doesn't suit me

```java
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.Method})
public @interface doSmthg {
    String value();
}
```

the test itself looks like this:

```
@Test
@doSmthg
public void userTest(){
}
```

Answer:
follow: [a link](https://github.com/amareshp/testng-examples)!

Comment: how about testng [method invocation listener](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#invokedmethodlistener)?

Comment: Когда вы хотите написать свою аннотацию, вам надо создать своего слушателя, который будет обрабатывать ваши анноташки
**Лучший для этого пример описан тут:**
[testg-own-annotation](https://github.com/amareshp/testng-examples)

Comment: When you know the answer, post it as answer, not as a comment. And use the English language.